Limit of $\mathrm{tr}(P(\alpha QP + I)^{-1})$ as $\alpha \to \infty$?
Say that $P, Q$ are two real, symmetric positive semidefinite, possibly singular matrices. What is the limit
$$
\lim_{\alpha \to \infty} \mathrm{tr}(P(\alpha QP + I)^{-1})?
$$
Simultaneously diagonalizable case: $P, Q$ are simultaneously diagonalizable, we have
$$
\sum_{j} \frac{p_j}{\alpha q_j p_j + 1} \to \sum_{j : q_j =0} p_j.
$$
Above, $p_j, q_j$ are the eigenvalues of $P, Q$. However, when $P, Q$ are not simultaneously diagonalizable I am less sure how to proceed.
If $P$ is invertible:  Use spectral decomposition $Q =UDU^T$ and $R = U^T P U$. Then
$$
P(\alpha Q P + I)^{-1}= U R (\alpha D R + I)^{-1} U^T.
$$
Thus, the trace is
$$
\mathrm{tr}(R(\alpha DR + I)^{-1}) \to \mathrm{tr}(\Pi_Q^\ast P \Pi_Q), 
$$
where $\Pi_Q$ is the projection onto the kernel of $Q$.
Question: I am not sure how to proceed in the case that both are singular, or $P$ is singular and $Q$ is not.
Update: I seem to have found a proof, but if someone could check my reasoning, I would be grateful.

If one of the matrices is positive definite, the two matrices are simultaneously diagonalizable. And, if you add a well-chosen matrix to one of the two, this will give a positive definte matrix.

I am not sure I follow. Can you be more precise?

Where do you need precisions in what I wrote?

Simultaneous diagonalization from Wikipedia may help.

If your observation is that when (say) $P$ is invertible, we have $(\alpha Q + P^{-1})^{-1}$, I don't see what that helps too much.

As alpha goes to infinity , one over alpha goes to 0, so the limit would seem to be 0 in the diagonal case.

Sorry, it should be $q_j = 0.$

Some thoughts.
Using $(\alpha P^{1/2}QP^{1/2} + I)P^{1/2}
= \alpha P^{1/2}QP + P^{1/2}
= P^{1/2}(\alpha QP + I)$, we have
$$P^{1/2}(\alpha QP + I)^{-1}
= (\alpha P^{1/2}QP^{1/2} + I)^{-1}P^{1/2},$$
and
$$P(\alpha QP + I)^{-1}
= P^{1/2}(\alpha P^{1/2}QP^{1/2} + I)^{-1}P^{1/2}.$$
Let $P^{1/2}QP^{1/2} = UDU^\top$. We have
$$P(\alpha QP + I)^{-1}
= P^{1/2}U(\alpha D + I)^{-1}U^\top P^{1/2}.$$

You are done. The matrix $U(\alpha D + I)^{-1} U^T \to \Pi_Q$ as $\alpha \to \infty$. (Just write it in coordinates $1/(\alpha d_i + 1)$, and consider $d_i > 0 $ or $d_i = 0$.)

@DrewBrady Yes, obviously.

So, then you have obtained the same limit. It is $\mathrm{tr}(P\Pi_Q)$.

Define $P_\tau = P + \tau I$. We have
$$
\lim_{\beta \to 0^+} 
\mathrm{tr}(\beta P (QP + \beta I)^{-1}) 
=\lim_{\beta \to 0^+} 
 \lim_{\tau \to 0^+} 
\mathrm{tr} (\beta (Q + \beta P_\tau^{-1})^{-1}) = \mathrm{tr}(P \Pi_Q). 
$$
To obtain the final equation, we see that we can swap the limit and apply the $P$ nonsingular case from my post. To justify swapping the limit: we can replace each by the infimum over $\beta > 0, \tau > 0$, since the map
$
(\beta, \tau) \mapsto \mathrm{tr} (\beta (Q + \beta P_\tau^{-1})^{-1})
$
is increasing in $\beta$ for each fixed $\tau>0$ and vice versa for $\beta$.

When $P\succ0$, we have
$$
P(\alpha QP + I)^{-1}=\sqrt{P}\left(\alpha \sqrt{P}Q\sqrt{P} + I\right)^{-1}\sqrt{P}.
$$
By continuity, equality also holds when $P$ is positive semidefinite. Now let $X=\sqrt{P}\sqrt{Q}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}P(\alpha QP+I)^{-1}
=\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}\sqrt{P}\left(\alpha XX^T + I\right)^{-1}\sqrt{P}
=\sqrt{P}\left(I-XX^+\right)\sqrt{P}
\end{align*}
and hence
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}\operatorname{tr}P(I+\alpha QP)^{-1}
=\operatorname{tr}\left[(I - XX^+)P\right].
\end{align*}
Note that $I - XX^+$ is an orthogonal projection onto $\ker\left(\sqrt{Q}\sqrt{P}\right)$, not $\ker(Q)$. In general, neither any of the two null spaces is a subspace of the other.

Actually although I agree that these projectors are not the same, are you able to construct an example where the resulting traces are different" I had a little trouble with it.

I think two rank one matrices will work, if they’re not orthogonal.
